# Не получаю req.body после отправки запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

Отправляю запрос, но в req. body оказывается пусто {}, хотя я вижу что данные нормально уходят. Записывается та часть, которая не получается от пользователя, а задана мной по умолчанию. Где я что-то упустил?

**Тело запроса:**

```
document.forms.ourform.onsubmit = function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var userInput  = document.forms.ourform.textarea.value;
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/coffee');
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
 xhr.send(userInput);
}
```

**Обработчик:**

```
app.post('/coffee', coffeController.create);

 exports.create = function(sort, callback){
   db.get().collection('coffee').insert(sort, function(err, result) {
   callback(err, result);
 })
}

exports.create = function(req, res){
var sort = {
*//Вот здесь я получаю пустой {}, вместо body*
sort: req.body, 
 costs: {
  amount3: 50,
  amount5: 70
 }
}

coffee.create(sort, function(err, result){
 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
   return res.sendStatus(500);
 }
 res.send(sort);
 })
}
```

Прошу прощения за мешанину из кода.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: Вы что-то странное отправляете. У `x-www-form-urlencoded` формат должен быть `name=value`, а вы только `value` шлёте.

Comment: Я пробовал в разных вариантах, отправляемый через postman {"sort": "sort name"} application/json приходит нормально, отправляемое моим запросом значение  уже пустое оказывается .

Comment: Решил проблему. На данный момент передаю пользовательские данные в формате ключ = значение, и все обрабатывается.